# How to draw circle around bootstrap glyphicons heart icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, glyphicons

Red circle should appear arround heart icon like:

[image: s]

I tried

```
        <a href="/myurl">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart details-favoriteicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
```

CSS:

```
.details-favoriteicon {
    color: crimson;
}
```

But this draws heart without circle.

Bootstrap 3, glyphicons, fontawesome, jquery ui, ASP.NET MVC4 are used.

Comment: why would you expect changing colors to magically make a circle appear?

Comment: Fontaawesome and Glyphicons does not contain cricle around heart icon. I'm looking for a way to draw circle around heart using css or some other way.

Comment: `width:100px; height:100px; border-radius:100px;` will make a circle.

Comment: @Andrew I changed class to `.details-favoriteicon {
    color: crimson;
width:100px; height:100px; border-radius:100px;
}
` but circle does not appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.details-favoriteicon {
  border: 3px solid #ff0000;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 900px;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

The only issue I see is that glyph icons don't all take up the same width and height, so you may see some inconsistencies.  I'd also recommend you apply this as a more re-usable class like:

```
.glyphicon-border {
      border: 3px solid #000;
      padding: 12px;
      border-radius: 900px;
      font-size: 24px;
}
```

And then override the `border` color as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `border: 5px solid crimson;` and then apply `border-radius: 50%;`

From there you just have to tweak the `font-size` and `padding` until it fits.

```css
.glyphicon-heart {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 12px 0 0 7px;
  
  font-size: 70px;
  color: crimson;
  border: 5px solid crimson;
  border-radius: 50%; /* circle */
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart details-favoriteicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css:

```
.details-favoriteicon{
    border: 5px solid #ea212d; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #ea212d;
    font-size: 60px;
    padding: 7px 12px 4px 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```css
.details-favoriteicon {
  color: crimson;
  border: 3px solid crimson;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="/myurl">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart details-favoriteicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Adjust padding to the size of your icon
1. Add a div to the anchor

```
.circle{
    border: 1px solid #559CAD;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 35% 5%;
   }
```

[image]